# Як правильно "зал" чи "зала"?

Tags: синоніми, розмовна-українська

В Академічному тлумачному словнику української мови можна знайти слово "зал", а "зала" у ньому визначається як його абсолютний синонім, але якщо можна погодитися з тим, що, наприклад, у словосполучені "глядацький зал", іменник "зал" справді можна замінити на "зала", то як бути з такими словами як "спортзал", "кінозал" чи "танцзал"? Чи можлива заміна у таких випадках, адже я також знайшов інформацію, що все ж таки у сучасній українській мові варіант "зал" є більш поширеним.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Правильно і так, і так. Аби довести, наведу статтю із сучасного [Словника української мови](http://services.ulif.org.ua/expl/Entry/index?wordid=30186&page=990):

> **ЗАЛ**, у, ч., **ЗА́ЛА**, и, ж.
>
> 1. Велике приміщення для багатолюдних зборів, засідань, занять і т. ін.
>
> Ясна *зала* вся світлом палає, Грім плескання, громада без ліку, Гомонить люд, співця викликає, – Він придбав собі славу велику!(Леся Українка);
>
> *Зал* засідань нагадує студентську аудиторію (І. Кириленко)
>
> 2. розм. Простора кімната, признач. для приймання гостей, розваг і т. ін.; вітальня.
>
> – Якого тут багато кімнат! – промовила Ганя. – От і багато! Перша кімната буде прихожа; друга – прийомна, третя – зала (І. Нечуй-Левицький);
>
> Зал є найважливішим приміщенням у будинку. Саме тут проводяться сімейні свята, чаювання, зустрічі з гостями сім'ї (із журн.).

Як приклад, ще у цьому словнику наводяться і такі поняття:

> (1) А́ктовий зал <А́ктова за́ла> – приміщення для урочистих зборів у навчальних закладах, установах.
>
> Прокопові здавалося, нiби вiн кохає Ольгу. Пам'ятає, як вперше привiв її на вечiрку *до актового залу*(В. Підмогильний);
>
> Він вийшов *із актової зали* й безцільно тинявся по порожніх шкільних коридорах (Б. Антоненко-Давидович);
>
> (2) Гіпости́льний зал <Гіпости́льна за́ла> – просторе крите приміщення палацу чи храму, стелю якого підпирають масивні колони (перев. в архітектурі Стародавнього Сходу); гіпостиль.
>
> Зліва від *гіпостильного залу* стоїть римський олтар, розписаний латинськими написами і присвячений імператорові Августу(з наук.-попул. літ.).

Також є ще експрес-урок від **Олександра Авременка у [Сніданку з 1+1](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=_Ze0Q-kIvYM)**, де він пояснює, що:

> ***Зал і зала - це паралельні родові форми***. Наприклад, *абрикос і абрикоса, птах і птаха, сусід і сусіда*.
>
> Використання цих форм пояснюється тим, що лексеми запозичені з різних мов:
>
> **Зал** - чол. р.; з німецької мови.
>
> **Зала** - жін. р.; з французької мови.

Проте, як Ви правильно зауважили, в українській мові є більш поширеним використання чоловічого роду: глядацький зал, спортивний зал, танцювальний зал.

Comment: Перша половина відповіді дублює джерело, згадане у запитанні. А друга не пояснює, чи можна слово *зала* використовувати у складних словах: *спротзала*. Мені здалося, що автор саме про це запитував.

Comment: @bytebuster, але автор посту основне питання поставив так: Як правильно “зал” чи “зала”? Я на нього відповіла. Щодо першої часнини відповіді, то мені, наприклад, не зрозуміло, чи це СУМ-20, чи СУМ-8. Наводжу СУМ-8 якнайбільш актуальне джерело. Щодо другої частини, я вказала, що Зал і зала - це паралельні родові форми, посилаючись на О. Авраменка. Вкінці зробила висновок, про який запитував автор: в українській мові є більш поширеним (!) використання чоловічого роду: глядацький зал, спортивний зал, танцювальний зал.